# How Max(char) really works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Some one please explain this:

I have column

```
        c_1
        ----
         A
         P
         H
         D

    Why?

    SELECT MAX(c_1) 
    FROM tbl_1 

Returns 
----
 P
```

I can only assume in hex: A = 41, P = 50, H = 48, D = 44; therefore P is the max.

This can't be the case because if I have

```
        c_1
        -----
         A
         |
         }
         ~

  Returns

   -----
     A
```

In Hex '~' is 7E, so why not '~'?

Comment: Did you expect another result?

Comment: good question...want to clarify what database you are doing this in?  I get the strange feeling there is a different answer for mssql vs mysql vs psql vs oracle

Comment: The result should be based on the defined sort order of your session as it involves a comparison: this value > other value

Comment: P was the correct answer, but I'm not sure why? All I can think of is Hex and Dec values

Comment: I can only assume in hex: A = 41, P = 50, H = 48, D = 44; therefore P is the max.  Your assumption is my understanding of how it works.  This is why if you have case sensitivity enabled AB vs ab sort differently.

Comment: Char is sorted in alphabetical order (which happens to be ASCII order as well).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MAX` on string columns chooses the value that is the highest in the given collation. I believe that all these strings compare in the same order in all collations. Update: After your edit this is no longer the case. You've proven that `MAX` does not follow code-point order.

Basically, you are getting [dictionary order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_order). Coincidentally, this happens to be code-point order as well for these specific four letters.